# Unable to delete a record due to foreign key restriction

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my database, I have a table called "departments". It contains information about the individual departments. The "name" column of this table is declared as the `primary key`.

Now one of my departments was removed. So I wish to remove that department record, and its related information, from my database. However, a `foreign key` restriction is preventing me from doing so. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: first remove data for that id from main table and then try to remove from current table...

Comment: This information is insufficient. As there is a relation we are talking about at least two tables here, you mention only one. Are there more relations with yet other tables? How is the relation defined? Wich database engine? Has cascading delete been implemented? If this sounds to complicated first study some resources about datarelations and make a test database with just two related tables.

Comment: Well, obviously, rows from other tables are still referencing that department - so you cannot remove it (that's the **whole point** of FK constraints!). You need to find and update/change those rows referencing the department to be removed, and once you've solved all those references, **THEN** you can delete the department

Comment: actually i was about to make a college website, so i was analyzing the whole concept in my mind, so i find this probelm...nd yeas there will be 2 and 3 tables associated with it to keep relation data...like student's table will have a foreign key for department id column.

Comment: @marks- yeah...i think your solution will work..thanx

Comment: So if you have students that still reference that department about to deleted - well, you need to know what to do with those - assign them to a new department or have them not assigned to any department - that's totally up to your business requirements. Point is: you cannot delete a department as long as other entities still reference / use it - and that's a "good thing" !

Answer (score 2):

When you have a tree of related rows in various tables, deletion must proceed from the bottom up.  In this case any students, employees and inventory of paperclips would need to be deleted (or reallocated to another department) before deleting the department.

Cascading deletes "solve" this problem.  They cause the related information to self destruct.  I find it is generally more appropriate to deal with the issue explicitly myself rather than arming a weapon that may come back and bite me somewhere tender.

Another consideration in many cases is maintaining history.  If you have an audit trail of material purchased by each department, then you can't delete the department without losing the history.  You could leave the relation out, but that would leave the history dangling with an invalid, or perhaps recycled, department id.  The typical solution is to add a flag to indicate that the department or other entity is `Inactive`.  Similarly, an inactive user account wouldn't allow logins, but any history associated with the user would remain intact.